# Search for AcoustID on Musicbrainz

Tags: web-services, fingerprinting, audio-fingerprinting, musicbrainz

Muscibrainz offers [acoustID](http://acoustid.org/) fingerprints, e.g., [here](http://musicbrainz.org/recording/d486f8c5-e19d-4892-a808-4047cd05d786/fingerprints)

However, i do not find a possibility to directly search for them (like it is possible for the [PUIDs](http://musicbrainz.org/search) or [echoprints](http://echoprint.musicbrainz.org/search))

Am I missing something?

acoustid.org offers the information I want, but not as a Acoustid WebService.

Example: given the fingerprint 
**453a8e75-ef90-4f31-a2b2-84494219bd3b**
I want the information provided by the following page:
http://acoustid.org/track/453a8e75-ef90-4f31-a2b2-84494219bd3b

(sidenote: I'm not interested in any fingerprint matching process, I just want all entries with a given acoustID)

Comment: 53a8e75-ef90-4f31-a2b2-84494219bd3b is not an "acoustid fingerprint", but an "acoustID" in that context. An mbid for a cluster of fingerprints.

Comment: yep, that was ambiguous. Is there any playce where the relationships between mbid, acoustid, whatever are documented?

Comment: Not that I know of, but: "acoustID" on musicbrainz.org = "acoustID track ID" on acoustid.org. And these are attached to MusicBrainz recordings. There are multiple fingerprints attached to one acoustID track ID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AcoustIDs are not included in the MusicBrainz database directly, so they can't be searched using the MusicBrainz Web Service. There is also an [AcoustID Web Service](http://acoustid.org/webservice).

You can't lookup by acoustID, yet. You can only lookup a fingerprint created by chromaprint:
[http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=8XaBELgH&meta=recordingids&duration=641&fingerprint=AQABz0qUkZK4oOfhL-CPc4e...](http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=8XaBELgH&meta=recordingids&duration=641&fingerprint=AQABz0qUkZK4oOfhL-CPc4e5C_wW2H2QH9uDL4cvoT8UNQ-eHtsE8cceeFJx-LiiHT-aPzhxoc-Opj_eI5d2hOFyMJRzfDk-QSsu7fBxqZDMHcfxPfDIoPWxv9C1o3yg44d_3Df2GJaUQeeR-cb2HfaPNsdxHj2PJnpwPMN3aPcEMzd-_MeB_Ej4D_CLP8ghHjkJv_jh_UDuQ8xnILwunPg6hF2R8HgzvLhxHVYP_ziJX0eKPnIE1UePMByDJyg7wz_6yELsB8n4oDmDa0Gv40hf6D3CE3_wH6HFaxCPUD9-hNeF5MfWEP3SCGym4-SxnXiGs0mRjEXD6fgl4LmKWrSChzzC33ge9PB3otyJMk-IVC6R8MTNwD9qKQ_CC8kPv4THzEGZS8GPI3x0iGVUxC1hRSizC5VzoamYDi-uR7iKPhGSI82PkiWeB_eHijvsaIWfBCWH5AjjCfVxZ1TQ3CvCTclGnEMfHbnZFA8pjD6KXwd__Cn-Y8e_I9cq6CR-4S9KLXqQcsxxoWh3eMxiHI6TIzyPv0M43YHz4yte-Cv-4D16Hv9F9C9SPUdyGtZRHV-OHEeeGD--BKcjVLOK_NCDXMfx44dzHEiOZ0Z44Rf6DH5R3uiPj4d_PKolJNyRJzyu4_CTD2WOvzjKH9GPb4cUP1Av9EuQd8fGCFee4JlRHi18xQh96NLxkCgfWFKOH6WGeoe4I3za4c5hTscTPEZTES1x8kE-9MQPjT8a8gh5fPgQZtqCFj9MDvp6fDx6NCd07bjx7MLR9AhtnFnQ70GjOcV0opmm4zpY3SOa7HiwdTtyHa6NC4e-HN-OfC5-OP_gLe2QDxfUCz_0w9l65HiPAz9-IaGOUA7-4MZ5CWFOlIfe4yUa6AiZGxf6w0fFxsjTOdC6Itbh4mGD63iPH9-RFy909XAMj7mC5_BvlDyO6kGTZKJxHUd4NDwuZUffw_5RMsde5CWkJAgXnDReNEaP6DTOQ65yaD88HoeX8fge-DSeHo9Qa8cTHc80I-_RoHxx_UHeBxrJw62Q34Kd7MEfpCcu6BLeB1ePw6OO4sOF_sHhmB504WWDZiEu8sKPpkcfCT9xfej0o0lr4T5yNJeOvjmu40w-TDmqHXmYgfFhFy_M7tD1o0cO_B2ms2j-ACEEQgQgAIwzTgAGmBIKIImNQAABwgQATAlhDGCCEIGIIM4BaBgwQBogEBIOESEIA8ARI5xAhxEFmAGAMCKAURKQQpQzRAAkCCBQEAKkQYIYIQQxCixCDADCABMAE0gpJIgyxhEDiCKCCIGAEIgJIQByAhFgGACCACMRQEyBAoxQiHiCBCFOECQFAIgAABR2QAgFjCDMA0AUMIoAIMChQghChASGEGeYEAIAIhgBSErnJPPEGWYAMgw05AhiiGHiBBBGGSCQcQgwRYJwhDDhgCSCSSEIQYwILoyAjAIigBFEUQK8gAYAQ5BCAAjkjCCAEEMZAUQAZQCjCCkpCgFMCCiIcVIAZZgilAQAiSHQECOcQAQIc4QClAHAjDDGkAGAMUoBgyhihgEChFCAAWEIEYwIJYwViAAlHCBIGEIEAEIQAoBwwgwiEBAEEEOoEwBY4wRwxAhBgAcKAESIQAwwIowRFhoBhAE)

There are multiple fingerprints mapped to one AcoustID.

EDIT:
I opened a [ticket on MusicBrainz](http://tickets.musicbrainz.org/browse/MBS-6052)
and a <strike>[ticket for acoustid.org](https://bitbucket.org/acoustid/acoustid-server/issue/7/web-service-cant-search-by-acoustid)</strike>.

EDIT: What MB calls "AcoustID" is an "AcoustID track ID" on acoustid.org and you can access it via http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=8XaBELgH&meta=recordingids&trackid=453a8e75-ef90-4f31-a2b2-84494219bd3b (since 2011 already).
There is no documentation about that yet, but there will soon be.

EDIT:
**This is now documented in** http://acoustid.org/webservice#lookup_by_trackid

Answer (score 3):

You can in fact look up by AcoustID instead of using fingerprint and duration, it just appears to not be documented:

http://api.acoustid.org/v2/lookup?client=8XaBELgH&meta=recordingids+recordings&trackid=453a8e75-ef90-4f31-a2b2-84494219bd3b

Answer (score 0):

When you get some details back from AcoustID you can then use them manually like this

http://musicbrainz.org/artist/53b106e7-0cc6-42cc-ac95-ed8d30a3a98e

http://musicbrainz.org/release/189002e7-3285-4e2e-92a3-7f6c30d407a2

More details here https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Identifier